# client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, gerrit

When I execute cmd `git fetch`, I get the following error:

```
remote: Counting objects: 112, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (2739/2739)
client_loop: send disconnect: Broken pipe02 MiB | 1.09 MiB/s
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Do you know what cause this error, and how can I to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have stable network connection and you git server is stable too? If so, set verbose mode and run git command again, it should provide all necessary debug information that will help you find issue

```
export GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1
export GIT_TRACE=1
export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of your internet problem. Increase your internet speed and push again.